# Bash: sort CSV on date by month,day

Tags: date, sort, csv

I've searched unsuccessfully for a solution to this problem.

I have a CSV file with a date field I'm trying to sort by both month and day.

CSV format :
`name,email,phone,date`

The date field format is `m/d/yy`  as in 1/3/84

I can sort by month

```
sort -t',' -n -k4 < $file`
```

but I can't wrap my head around splitting the date field and then sorting on k1 and k2, if that makes sense or is even remotely close.

This is clearly wrong `

```
cat $file | sort -t',' -n -k4 | sort -t'/' -n -k1 -k2
```

as the output is only sorted by day and k1 includes everything before the first `/`.

Looking to learn, not be spoon-fed.

EDIT:

Sample CSV

```
Name,Email,Phone,Birthday
MarkW.,email@email.com,(555) 444-4444,6/24/85
GeorgeT.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1413,4/2/82
BobA.,email@email.com,(555) 555-5050,11/15/85
TimP.,email@email.com,,4/11/18
JohnM.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1317,4/25/13
MikeT.,email@email.com,(555) 555-2114,4/10/91
BobR.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1383,7/13/14
TomW.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1980,12/25/08
JamesS.,email@email.com,(555) 555-2150,6/12/15
TimC.,email@email.com,(555) 555-8048,3/17/08
WallyG.,email@email.com,,7/21/00
KeithD.,email@email.com,,12/29/12
DaveM.,email@email.com,,1/10/48
DanMc.,email@email.com,(555) 555-6863,5/19/88
DickM.,email@email.com,(555) 555-9333,11/23/13
KenB.,email@email.com,(555) 555-6891,1/2/04
DaveMc.,email@email.com,,
MichaelL.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1575,9/15/13
RoryB.,email@email.com,(555) 555-555,1/25/17
```

Sample Output, best I've been able to come up with using

`sort -t',' -n -k4 < $file`

Expected output would be 1/10/84 appearing after 1/2/04 for example.

```
DaveMc.,email@email.com,,
Name,Email,Phone,Birthday
DaveM.,email@email.com,,1/10/48
KenB.,email@email.com,(555) 555-6891,1/2/04
RoryB.,email@email.com,(555) 555-555,1/25/17
TimC.,email@email.com,(555) 555-8048,3/17/08
GeorgeT.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1413,4/2/82
JohnM.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1317,4/25/13
MikeT.,email@email.com,(555) 555-2114,4/10/91
TimP.,email@email.com,,4/11/18
DanMc.,email@email.com,(555) 555-6863,5/19/88
JamesS.,email@email.com,(555) 555-2150,6/12/15
MarkW.,email@email.com,(555) 444-4444,6/24/85
BobR.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1383,7/13/14
WallyG.,email@email.com,,7/21/00
MichaelL.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1575,9/15/13
BobA.,email@email.com,(555) 555-5050,11/15/85
DickM.,email@email.com,(555) 555-9333,11/23/13
KeithD.,email@email.com,,12/29/12
TomW.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1980,12/25/08
```

It's sorted by month but I'm trying to also sort by day

Comment: Give an example of the text and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, with [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) - adding new month and day fields, sorting by them, then removing:

```
$ mlr --csvlite put '
    dmy = splitnv($Birthday,"/"); $m = dmy[1]; $d = dmy[2]
  ' then sort -n m,d then cut -x -f m,d file.csv
Name,Email,Phone,Birthday
KenB.,email@email.com,(555) 555-6891,1/2/04
DaveM.,email@email.com,,1/10/48
RoryB.,email@email.com,(555) 555-555,1/25/17
TimC.,email@email.com,(555) 555-8048,3/17/08
GeorgeT.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1413,4/2/82
MikeT.,email@email.com,(555) 555-2114,4/10/91
TimP.,email@email.com,,4/11/18
JohnM.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1317,4/25/13
DanMc.,email@email.com,(555) 555-6863,5/19/88
JamesS.,email@email.com,(555) 555-2150,6/12/15
MarkW.,email@email.com,(555) 444-4444,6/24/85
BobR.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1383,7/13/14
WallyG.,email@email.com,,7/21/00
MichaelL.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1575,9/15/13
BobA.,email@email.com,(555) 555-5050,11/15/85
DickM.,email@email.com,(555) 555-9333,11/23/13
TomW.,email@email.com,(555) 555-1980,12/25/08
KeithD.,email@email.com,,12/29/12
DaveMc.,email@email.com,,
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware Miller existed but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @KenDeWitt there may be a better way (in fact, there may be a better way even with Miller - I'm only just starting to learn it)